# how to make dafault crop section stretched in ngimgcrop angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Can I make crop area of ngimgcrop stretch to fullest of the width of image.
I simply want when I click on browse the crop portion which we drag need to be stretch to the fullest width or height.

Here is of screenshot exactly what I want:

[image]

I have tried with `ng-img-crop.js` but unable to find solution.

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngImgCrop'])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myImage='';
  $scope.myCroppedImage='';

  var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
    var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
      $scope.$apply(function($scope){
        $scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
      });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
  angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change',handleFileSelect);
});
```

```css
.cropArea {
  background: #E4E4E4;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:500px;
  height:350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop/master/compile/minified/ng-img-crop.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop/master/compile/minified/ng-img-crop.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>
  <div class="cropArea">
    <img-crop image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage" area-type="square" result-image-format="image/jpeg" area-min-size="150"></img-crop>
  </div>
  <div>Cropped Image:</div>
  <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}" /></div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rw6q9/2579/

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you can't do this with this plugin (Also, you can only crop a square area so in the most of the cases, you can't set the area as full width **and** height).

You can use [`ngCropper`](https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper) - a angular module based on the very good jQuery plugin [`cropper`](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/).

This plugin has much more options so you can customize it exactly as you want.

Like this (See it in Full page mode or in the [bin](http://output.jsbin.com/tukamos):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngCropper']);

app.controller('Main', function($scope, $timeout, Cropper) {
  var file, data;

  /**
   * Method is called every time file input's value changes.
   * Because of Angular has not ng-change for file inputs a hack is needed -
   * call `angular.element(this).scope().onFile(this.files[0])`
   * when input's event is fired.
   */
  $scope.onFile = function(blob) {
    Cropper.encode((file = blob)).then(function(dataUrl) {
      $scope.dataUrl = dataUrl;
      $timeout(showCropper);  // wait for $digest to set image's src
    });
  };

  /**
   * Croppers container object should be created in controller's scope
   * for updates by directive via prototypal inheritance.
   * Pass a full proxy name to the `ng-cropper-proxy` directive attribute to
   * enable proxing.
   */
  $scope.cropper = {};
  $scope.cropperProxy = 'cropper.first';

  /**
   * When there is a cropped image to show encode it to base64 string and
   * use as a source for an image element.
   */
  $scope.preview = function() {
    if (!file || !data) return;
    Cropper.crop(file, data).then(Cropper.encode).then(function(dataUrl) {
      ($scope.preview || ($scope.preview = {})).dataUrl = dataUrl;
    });
  };

  /**
   * Use cropper function proxy to call methods of the plugin.
   * See https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper#methods
   */
  $scope.clear = function(degrees) {
    if (!$scope.cropper.first) return;
    $scope.cropper.first('clear');
  };

  $scope.scale = function(width) {
    Cropper.crop(file, data)
    .then(function(blob) {
      return Cropper.scale(blob, {width: width});
    })
    .then(Cropper.encode).then(function(dataUrl) {
      console.log('bbb');
      ($scope.preview || ($scope.preview = {})).dataUrl = dataUrl;
    });
  }

  /**
   * Object is used to pass options to initalize a cropper.
   * More on options - https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper#options
   */
  $scope.options = {
    maximize: true,
    aspectRatio: 2 / 1,
    crop: function(dataNew) {
      data = dataNew;
    },
    preview: '.preview-container'
  };

  /**
   * Showing (initializing) and hiding (destroying) of a cropper are started by
   * events. The scope of the `ng-cropper` directive is derived from the scope of
   * the controller. When initializing the `ng-cropper` directive adds two handlers
   * listening to events passed by `ng-cropper-show` & `ng-cropper-hide` attributes.
   * To show or hide a cropper `$broadcast` a proper event.
   */
  $scope.showEvent = 'show';
  $scope.hideEvent = 'hide';

  function showCropper() { $scope.$broadcast($scope.showEvent); }
  function hideCropper() { $scope.$broadcast($scope.hideEvent); }
});
```

```css
.img-preview {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.preview-lg {
  width: 263px;
  height: 148px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/koorgoo/ngCropper/master/dist/ngCropper.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/koorgoo/ngCropper/master/dist/ngCropper.all.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Main">
  <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onFile(this.files[0])">

  <div ng-if="dataUrl" class="img-container">
    <img ng-if="dataUrl" ng-src="{{dataUrl}}" width="800"
         ng-cropper
         ng-cropper-proxy="cropperProxy"
         ng-cropper-show="showEvent"
         ng-cropper-hide="hideEvent"
         ng-cropper-options="options">

    <div class="preview-container preview-lg img-preview">
      <img />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was updated my answer.. Please read the docs of the both angular and regular plugin. You will find there whatever you want..